# Compiling GNUTLS gives config.status:error: cannot find input file: 'guile/pre-inst-guile.in'

Tags: linux, makefile, compiler-errors, guile

I'm trying to compile GNUTLS through a VirtualBox debian VM. I've installed all dependencies yet I still get 
    `config.status:error: cannot find input file: 'guile/pre-inst-guile.in'`

I've already performed `sudo apt-get install guile-2.0-dev` and I've also done a manual download and make install of guile 2.2 as well.

```
configure: checking for guile 2.2
configure: found guile 2.2
checking for guile-2.2... /usr/bin/guile-2.2
checking for Guile version >= 2.2... 2.2.4
checking for guild-2.2... (cached) /usr/local/bin/guild
checking for guile-config-2.2... /usr/bin/guile-config-2.2
checking for Guile site directory... /usr/local/share/guile/site/2.2
checking for Guile site-ccache directory using pkgconfig... /usr/local/lib/guile/2.2/site-ccache
checking for Guile extensions directory... /usr/local/lib/guile/2.2/extensions
checking for GUILE... yes
checking whether GNU Guile is recent enough... yes
checking whether gcc supports -fgnu89-inline... yes
checking for scm_gc_malloc_pointerless... yes
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/libopts/Makefile
config.status: error: cannot find input file: `guile/pre-inst-guile.in'
```

Why am I getting this error message and how can I fix it?

Comment: Autotools and Guile are a bane on the Internet. I have not been able to get GnuTLS to use my local copy of Guile despite months of trying. I _think_ the only way it works in practice is if `--prefix=/usr` and GnuTLS happens to use the same version that is installed in `/usr`. Otherwise, you can forget about it... Use `--disable-guile` when configuring GnuTLS. It sidesteps all the Guile problems.

Comment: This is the wrong place if you ever want it to be fixed. Please open an issue at https://gitlab.com/gnutls/gnutls/issues and add your `config.log` file. Include the tarball version resp. the commit id you are working with.

Comment: The missing file `guile/pre-inst-guile.in` is part of git master (commit 9ba468c457478c1c1fbdd772b45c1564584a160e). Also it's part of the latest tarball (ftp://ftp.gnutls.org/gcrypt/gnutls/v3.6/gnutls-3.6.8.tar.xz).
So why is this file missing in your guile/ directory ?